# Cas-protected site behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, proxypass, cas

My setup is:

- Cas server (lets say url `https://localhost:8443/cas-server/`)
- A cas-protected website hosted on a tomcat-server, running cas-client (lets say (`https://localhost:4448/myApp`)
- A httpd apache2, with mod auth cas, and proxy_http, which is used as a reverse proxy. (`http://localhost:80`)

What I want to do, is to configure the reverse proxy to something like this:

```
<Location /proxyTest >
      ProxyPass https://localhost:4448/myApp
      ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:4448/myApp
</Location>
```

And then be able to write

```
https://localhost/proxyTest
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:4448/myApp
```

And this works well, I get redirected, I get the cas-ticket, I get authenticated etc.
The PROBLEM, is that the cas-login page url shows:

```
https://localhost:8443/cas-server/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4448%2Fmyapp
```

And after login, the url shown in my browser is:

```
https://localhost:4448/myApp
```

So the redirection doesen't work properly...somewhere along the way, I get sent back to the non-proxied URL. Most likely by the cas-client.
How can I set up such a proxy to work properly, so that all of this is transparent once I got a valid ticket?

Is using tomcat's AJP involved? Or configuring and using the mysterious cas proxy callback stuff in the cas-client,that I never understood how to use? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ProxyPassReverse directive is what rewrites the URL returned by Apache on redirects, etc. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/227522/do-proxypass-directives-need-a-proxypassreverse-directive) for a concise explanation.

I think what you are looking for is

```
<Location /proxyTest>
    ProxyPass https://localhost:4448/myApp
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost/proxyTest
</Location>
```

Here you are using http(s), so AJP is not involved. [According to the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html), a ProxyPassReverse is not required for AJP, so you could have something like

```
<Location /proxyText>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:4448/myApp
</Location>
```